# How can a UITextView listen on its own changes without delegate

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a custom UITextView subclass. The purpose is to support a placeholder, not natively supported for UITextView. The text view needs to listen on its own changes in order to show / hide the placeholder label. But I cannot use a delegate because the user class might reset the delegate to itself. How can I achieve this without any delegate methods ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498158/intercept-objective-c-delegate-messages-within-a-subclass ? Using an procotol interceptor, like a man in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a little strange that you can't use a `delegate`, and it might be worth checking there's not a better architecture that would allow it, but if it's not feasible you could use notifications to alert you to activity in the `textView`.

TextViews issue `textDidBeginEditingNotification`, `textDidChangeNotification`, and `textDidEndEditingNotification`.

You could subscribe to these notifications, compare the text value against a stored version, and respond accordingly.

Details on this page: [Apple docs for textView notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618609-textdidchangenotification)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the text value's changes, and act upon it.
If there is at least one character, then we hide the placeholder, if there are 0 characters, we unhide the placeholder.

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView {

   override var text: String! {
        didSet (newValue) {
            let shouldHide = newValue.count > 0
            placeholder.isHidden = shouldHide
        }
    }
}
```